# How to kill an invisible process?

Tags: linux, netbeans, kill, top

I have a program that crashed, its GUI is frozen, and I would like to kill it.

However there is **no trace** of it among the current processes.

I tried both `top` and `ps -A`, but I got nothing.

The program is NetBeans 7.2. Could the reason be that it is a Java program, and what I need to kill is Java itself?

Thank you!

System: OpenSuse 11.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's java.

I'd try:

```
ps auwwwx | grep '[j]ava'
```

Then see which is the netbeans one. You could also try running in a terminal:

```
xkill
```

and click on the NetBeans window to kill it

Comment: I got two processes from ps. I could kill just one of them, the other seemed to be immortal. With xkill I solved the problem. Thank you!